# Get age from record in table: T-SQL

Tags: t-sql

So each record on my table has a `datetime` timestamp column.

How do I return the age (in hours), of these records in the database?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
select DATEDIFF(hour,timestamp,getdate()) as hours_old
from myTable
```

Answer (score 2):

```
datediff(hour,[Your Column], getdate())
```

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189794.aspx

Comment: Thanks! I saw that but wasn't sure how it implement it.

Answer (score 0):

Use the datediff function.

```
select datediff(hour, getdate(), dob) as age
   from ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Since `datediff(hour,'2000-01-01 00:59','2000-01-01 01:00')` returns 1, due to the (counterintuitive) way `datediff` works, you may want something more accurate:

```
select DATEDIFF(minute,the_timestamp,getdate()) / 60
  from TheTable
```